# Image in header not placed correctly

Tags: html, css

Need the image to fill up the rest of the space in the .container class

I have tried setting the width of the image in CSS to `width: 100%`, but it gives me this:
Picture 1: https://ibb.co/9yKJgvF

If I remove that attribute, it gives me this:
Picture 2: https://ibb.co/K0HpkvJ

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo_container">
            <h1>Hotel<span>Inn</span></h1>
        </div>
        <img src="../images/sample1.jpg" alt="Image of Hotel">
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}

#logo_container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

#logo_container h1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.container img{
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
```

I trying to make it such that the height of the image is the same as that in Picture 2 while the image will fill up the rest of the space until it touches the words 'HotelInn'

Comment: In css of '.container img' can you try to add: 'width: 100%; text-align: left;', does that work?

Answer (score 0):

first of all dont use float for this purpose use absolute layout

remove float in .img

In .container add

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

In .img add

```
 position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
```

this will strech out the image I suggest to use image according to it.....

if you want to strech out the image with perfect ratio use `height : auto`
and add `overflow : hidden` in .container